# Send event message to AWS MSK in Streamsets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk, streamsets

I have a Streamsets pipeline that sends events to AWS SNS currently (Using HTTP client). I now have a requirement to send these events to AWS MSK instead of AWS SNS.

I am not finding a relevant documentation to start with this. Don't know where and how to start.

Can someone help in pointing to a relevant documentation which will be much helpful in starting this change?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

MSK is just a managed service around Apache Kafka. In StreamSets there is a [Kafka connector](https://docs.streamsets.com/platform-controlhub/controlhub/UserGuide/ConnectionTypes/Kafka.html).

[MSK can use certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-authentication.html) (mTLS) for authentication, and this is the method that might work for StreamSets.